# Django Postgres encoding error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

Ok, I suspect the error has something to do with postgres. But I'm not sure.

I get an endcoding error in the admin:

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /admin/catalogos/tipoidfiscal/2/
```

That points the word "Cédula" which is comming directly from the database as the source of the error. The word is stored in a `Charfield` in the models.

What is strange is that I do not get the error if I'm working locally, it only happens on `Heroku`. : /   ?¿?

Also, I did a `pg_backup` to the local db and `pg_restore` it on the remote `Heroku Postgres`. Maybe I didn't set the correct encoding for the database when I did the `pg_dump`? I dont know, I'm kind of lost here. How can I check if it is the database, or if its not the db, where could the error be?

Comment: Some more stack trace will definitely help to find a solution.

Comment: Verify that the encoding in the remote and local databases are the same; from `psql` run `show lc_collate` and `show server_encoding`. You may need to adjust the dump and restore commands to reconcile them if they are different.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I couldn't solve it and I'm not working on that project anymore... what should I do, delete the question? I don't have access to the server in order to try any possible solutions ...